# tf.data.Dataset.zip(a, b) changes order of elements if a was shuffled

Tags: tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.x

I am preparing a dataset and then training a model before storing the outputs (for the purpose of knowledge distillation)

In order to store them in the tfrecords format i need to use the .zip() function.

I reproduced the bug/mistake with the following code.
My actual training files are hundreds of lines so I didn't include them here.

I use tensorflow 2.1. and python 3.7 on ubuntu 18.04

#### The problem I can't solve is:

The data is shuffled (which is okay). But after zipping the tuples have a different order to each other (which is not okay).

```
import tensorflow as tf 
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1,2,3,4, 5])

#prepare dataset for training
batch_size=2
ds = ds.cache().repeat().shuffle(buffer_size=5, reshuffle_each_iteration=True).batch(batch_size)

#create model. here: map identity function
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x , input_shape=(1,))])

#train with model.fit()

#make predictions. 
pred = model.predict(ds, steps=5//batch_size)

#prepare for saving to tfrecords
ds = ds.unbatch()
ds = ds.take(5)
pred = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(pred)
combined = tf.data.Dataset.zip((ds, pred))

#show unwanted behaviour
for (a),c in combined:
    print(a,c)
```

output of code snippet shows that the elements per line don't match. (eg line 1: 3 should be mapped to 3)

```
tf.Tensor(3, shape=(), dtype=int32) tf.Tensor([4.], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(1, shape=(), dtype=int32) tf.Tensor([1.], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(4, shape=(), dtype=int32) tf.Tensor([1.], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(3, shape=(), dtype=int32) tf.Tensor([2.], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: any update here? I am seeing something similar. Zip also seems to be very slow.

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow applies shuffle at each iteration through the dataset.
Zip is one of those iterations, this is why the order in model.predict will not match the order in zip when (both times there is a shuffle)

anyway, for predict you do not really need to shuffle the dataset. The predictions should not depend on what the model sees in a previous prediction.

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow shuffles the first axis so if your tensor shape is `(x,)` this will change the order of your elements; here is a test

```py
a = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.constant([[x] for x in range(10)]))
b = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.constant([[x] for x in range(10)]))
c = tf.data.Dataset.zip((a,b)).shuffle(10)
for i,j in c.batch(1):
    print(i.numpy(),j.numpy())
```

and the output is

```
[[3]] [[3]]
[[6]] [[6]]
[[5]] [[5]]
[[8]] [[8]]
[[7]] [[7]]
[[1]] [[1]]
[[2]] [[2]]
[[0]] [[0]]
[[9]] [[9]]
[[4]] [[4]]
```

as you can see the order has been preserved but the items on the first axis of each tensor has been shuffled.